# Python Site Search Assistance

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I decided to combine my love for tequila and being a nerd and am trying to read the site below for a particular bottle I like that doesn't come in too often. I don't have time to drive regularly to the store, so I thought I'd put code to it and have it send a chime when the bottle is found/able to be added to a cart.

I'm having trouble in reading a piece of the webpage though and am looking for assistance. I think I'm very close. The urls are below. The difference between these websites is the Add to Cart button vs the Out of Stock button and the box that says pickup. One says In stock while the other says Out of stock online and in store. I'm looking for help reading that particular information and if it says Add to Cart or "In stock", then send me a chime.

https://www.totalwine.com/spirits/tequil...rules=true

https://www.totalwine.com/spirits/tequil...rules=true

My code is below but it's not reading the if statement properly. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I think I'm close but I'm stuck!!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import requests
 
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36', 'referer': 'https://www.google.com'}
nowdatetime.datetime.now()
 
print('============================================================================')
 
url1 = 'https://www.totalwine.com/spirits/tequila/reposado/clase-azul-reposado-tequila/p/218990175?s=101&igrules=true'
 
response1 = requests.get(url1, headers=headers)
 
if response1.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response1.content, 'html.parser')
       if soup.find(string="add to cart"):
           print(now, "They have it")
           os.system('afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Blow.aiff')
       else:
           print(now, "They don't have it")
 
else:
print('Error accessing web page. Error:', response1.status_code)
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Welcome to the site! What error are you getting? A syntax error should be there, because you didn't put the apostrophes correctly. I tune in this code snippet: `print(now, 'They don't have it')` It should be like this: `print(now, "They don't have it")` Because Python recognizes the single character in `don't` as the end of the string.

Comment: What do you mean "it's not reading the if statement properly"?  Please describe what the code **actually does**.  Do you get an error message?  Do you get some unwanted behavior?

Comment: Great catch, it should have double quotes and not single quotes.  I fixed that in my code,  What is happening is that I have an issue with the following portion of the code:

if soup.find(string="add to cart"):

Something about the above search isn't correct.  I was hoping someone could right click the link I included and look at the source to see if I'm looking for the correct string.  I'm pretty new to Python so your current help and any new help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.totalwine.com/spirits/tequila/reposado/clase-azul-reposado-tequila/p/218990175?s=101&igrules=true'

#For this URL the script prints "Add to cart":
#url = 'https://www.totalwine.com/spirits/tequila/reposado/clase-azul-reposado-tequila/p/104416750-1'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

availibility = soup.select_one('button[data-sku]').text
print(availibility)
```

Prints:

```
Out of stock
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  When I run this new code, I receive the following error:   availibility = soup.select_one('button[data-sku]').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Any idea what this means/how to get around it?

Comment: @CaptainNewb Maybe you've received captcha page? Try to do `print(soup)` and check if the tags are there.

Comment: I changed print(availability) to print(soup) and receive the same 'NoneType' error message.

Comment: Could it be an additional module needed other than import requests and from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Comment: no Captcha page.  Any additional thoughts?  I've hit a wall on this one